# References request: Introduction to K3 surface.

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, complex-geometry, k3-surfaces

Are there some good books or survey papers about K3 surface? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see [K3 surface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K3_surface) on Wikipedia where there's sevral references and links.